Python hvplot Explorer limit of 10,000 point
Using Python hvplot Explorer is giving nuisance Line plot when using over 10,000 points.
Is that a bug? can I configure the threshold value?
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import hvplot.pandas

N=1001
Range = 10
DF = []
for n in range(Range):
    x = np.linspace(0.0, 6.4, num=N)
    y = np.sin(x) + n/10
    df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})
    df['#'] = n 
    DF.append(df)

DF = pd.concat(DF)
print(f'param number= {N*Range}')
DF.hvplot.explorer(x='x', y='y', by = ['#'], kind='line')

When Number of points is <10,000

When Number of points is >10,000


Digging in the hvplot code I found in \site-packages\hvplot\ui.py
MAX_ROWS = 10000. Changing to MAX_ROWS = 100001 solved the issue.
Also, change df = df.sample(n=MAX_ROWS) --> df = df.sample(n=MAX_ROWS).).sort_index()
